# powershell script not continuing after error. silenlycontinue already in code

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to start a process if the process is not running on remote machines. The problem is that if one of the remote machines is not reachable the script just stops and uses the first "IF" part of the script.

When I put a reachable machine first on the list, everything is working. When I put an unreachable machine first, the script just starts the process without checking the second machine on my list.

I'm starting the script with a batch file as administrator:

```
powershell -Command Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Force
powershell -Command "\\networkpath\bla.ps1"
```

The script:

```bsh
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'

$ProcessName = “processname”
$Computername = Get-Content \\networkpath\computernamen.txt |
                ForEach-Object { $_ -split ',' }

$ProcessActive = Get-Process $ProcessName -ComputerName $Computername -EV Err -EA SilentlyContinue

if ($ProcessActive -eq $null) {
    Start-Process -FilePath "\\networkpath\aktuell.bla"
} else {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Programm gesperrt.", "Info", 0)
}
```

Comment: You will need to put your `$ProcessActive` line and your entire IF statement in a Foreach loop in order to loop through all of the computer names in your list from `$Computername`. Otherwise it is only running those lines one time, rather than once for each computer name you have in computernamen.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood well you want to run a command or a process if another (or same) process is not running on any other listed machines, right ?

in this case you can try this :

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Runs a process if another or same process is not running on other computers.
.DESCRIPTION
    Search for a process (specified in -Process parameter) on computers (specified in -Computer or -List parameters).
    If not any process is found, it runs then another process (specifies in -Run parameter)
.PARAMETER Computer
    Specifies one or more computer name
    This value(s) can come from the pipeline
.PARAMETER List
    Specifies path of a file which contains a list of computer names
    The file can contain computer names one per line, or in one line separated by ',' or ';'
.PARAMETER Process
    Specifies the name of the process to check on computers
.INPUTS
    This script accept from pipeline one or more System.String representing computer names
.OUTPUTS
    None
#>


[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Default')]
Param (
    # Specifies one or more computer name
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
               Position=0,
               ValueFromPipeline=$true,
               ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
               ValueFromRemainingArguments=$false, 
               ParameterSetName='Default')]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [Alias("ComputerName")] 
    [string[]]
    $Computer,
    # Specifies path of a computer list file.
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
               Position=0,
               ParameterSetName = 'FromFile')]
    [ValidateScript( { Test-Path $_ -PathType Leaf } )]
    [Alias("ListFile")]
    [string]
    $List,
    # Specifies the process name
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
               Position=1)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [Alias("ProcessName")]
    [String]
    $Process,
    # Specifies the process to run
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,
        Position = 2)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [Alias("ProcessToRun")]
    [String]
    $Run
)
# Set default ErrorAction setting
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
# If current Parameter Set is 'FromFile' (-List parameter was used followed by a file path)
If ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'FromFile') {
    # For each line in the provided file...
    Get-Content -Path $List | ForEach-Object {
        # Test line:
        switch ($_) {
            # If any ',' is found in the line, then split each value separated by a ',' in Computer array of strings and process next line
            { $_ -match '*,*' } { [string[]]$Computer = $_.Split(',');continue }
            # If any ';' is found in the line, then split each value separated by a ';' in Computer array of strings and process next line
            { $_ -match '*;*' } { [string[]]$Computer = $_.Split(';');continue }
            # In any other case...
            Default {
                # If Computer variable does not exists, create an empty array of strings
                if (!$Computer) { [string[]]$Computer = @() }
                # Add line content as a new item of the Computer array of strings
                [string[]]$Computer += , $_
            }
        }
    }
}
# Set a flag to False
$isRunning = $false
# For each computer ($item) in Computer array...
foreach ($item in $Computer) {
    # If Get-Process command for provided Process on current computer found something, set flag to True
    if (Get-Process -Name $Process -ComputerName $item -ErrorVariable Err) { $isRunning = $true }
}
# If Flag equals True (If the searched Process was already running on any of the listed computers)...
if ($isRunning) {
    # Start process provided in -Run parameter
    Start-Process -FilePath $Run
# Else (no listed computer seems to run the searched process)
} else {
    #To display a message through dialog box
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Your message","Title", 0) | Out-Null
    #To display a message in Console
    "Your message" | Out-Host
}
```

copy and save it in a PS1 file, then I recommend you to type to know how to use it :

```
Get-Help .\YourScript.ps1 -Full
```

I did it very fast and didn't take time to test it. Please let me know if it works.